# 1920x360 resolution in raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, resolution, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

We have a special monitor which has 1920x360 resolution. I am trying to setup resolution from raspberry pi with config.txt file but no success. How may I achieve to set proper resolution?

Thanks

Comment: What you done so far ? Please be specific.

Comment: I changed following lines Framebuffer_width=1920
Framebuffer_height=360

Comment: Where you changed ? In config.txt ?

Comment: Yes in config.txt file Monitor is specially designed from kortek. 28" TFT-LCD Monitor (Panoramic 32" 1/3 cut)